# Runtime error when using nVIDIA compiler to generate a shared library for my GNU compiler to link

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, cuda, shared-libraries

I want to use nVIDIA compiler to generate a shared library for my GNU compiler to link. Everything goes well until runtime. Following is the detail. Thanks!

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void fcudadriver();

int main()
{
  cout<<"Maine "<<endl;
  fcudadriver();
  return 0;
}
```

test.cu:

```
__global__ void fcuda()
{
}

void fcudadriver()
{
  fcuda<<<1,1>>>();
}
```

Compile:

```
nvcc --compiler-options '-fPIC' -o libtest.so --shared test.cu
g++ main.cpp -L. -ltest
```

Run:

```
./a.out
```

Results:

```
./a.out: error while loading shared libraries: libtest.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` needs to be in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for the runtime linker to find your shared library.

Try:

```
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:. ./a.out
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with g++. The runtime linker looks for shared libraries in a set of paths controlled by /etc/ld.so.conf and the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH. That's how things work on Linux. (And there's some caveats with setuid programs notable.) See `man ld.so`